# Angular HTMLElement not working from service but ok without it

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I am having some issues with some code but only when called from the service.

On app.component.html I have:

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

When I run this code:

```
this.targetElement = document.getElementById('wrapper') as HTMLElement;
```

from **app.component.ts** is works but I'm trying to move it to a service so I've done this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as mylib from '../../assets/index.js';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ViewerService {

  window: any = window;
  targetElement: HTMLElement;
  viewer: any;

  constructor() { }

  viewerInit() {
    this.targetElement = document.getElementById('wrapper') as HTMLElement;
    return this.targetElement;
  }

}
```

Then when I call the service from app.component.ts...

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.viewerService.viewerInit();
}
```

From the service the code will not work...

How can I fix this?

Comment: Create a stackblitz example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngOnInit` is early, move your logic to `AfterViewInit` hook.

```js
public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.viewerService.viewerInit();
}
```

---

If it's fine to pass the element into the service you can try the next thing:

```js
class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('wrapper') wrapper: TemplateRef<any>;

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.viewerService.viewerInit(this.wrapper.elementRef.nativeElement);
  }
}
```

and its template like that:

```html
<div #wrapper></div>
```

and the service like that:

```js
export class ViewerService {

  window: any = window;
  targetElement: HTMLElement;
  viewer: any;

  constructor() { }

  viewerInit(target?: HTMLElement) {
    if (target) {
      this.targetElement = target;
    }
    return this.targetElement;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same problem in ngAfterViewInit() so it must be something else

Comment: Hm.. looks like it's too early too, then let's try `ngAfterContentInit` instead, and then `ngAfterContentChecked`. Also would it be an option for you to pass the element into the service like `this.viewerService.viewerInit(this.element)`?

Comment: I've updated the answer in case if to pass the element is acceptable for you.

Comment: Still same issue...tried ngAfterContentInit too but still nothing. I might have to forget the idea of having the code in a service

Comment: what about `viewerInit(this.element)`? would it be an option for you?

Comment: I changed it to this in the service but still doesn't work. Is this what you mean? viewerInit(divId) {
  this.targetElement = document.getElementById(divId) as HTMLElement;
  return this.targetElement;
}

Comment: no no, not exactly, I've updated my answer to show how to extract it from the template.